# How to predetermine exception and use it

Tags: java

I have wished to create my own exception handling mechanism. For this reason, I am planning to use chain of responsibility pattern. But, since my background totaly comes from C++, I have a bit confused about how to throw own exception. What I want is throwing own exception like

```
public void foo() throws OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError { // body }
```

How can I predetermine exception like `OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError` and use it like this

```
public void foo() throws OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError { // body }
```

Comment: Does `OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError` extends `Exception`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: `throw new OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError();`

Comment: Thumbs up if you like my answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a normal java class that inherits from `java.lang.Exception`.

E.g., in `OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError.java`

```
public class OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError extends Exception 
{
    /** Constructor with exception message */
    public OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

in your class, you can then throw the exception like this:

```
public void foo() throws OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError {
    // ...       

    if(somethingBadHappens) 
    {
        throw new OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError("Something bad happened");
    }

    // ...       
}
```

Comment: Should I create a class for each exception or can I create enumeration and than use it ?

Comment: It is common to create a class for each exception. If you have several exceptions, you could consider to put them together in a separate package.

Comment: For each class, there is just constructor being implemented. Is it awkward ?

Comment: No. See, for example, this code from the Java Framework: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/UnknownHostException.java - they are exactly doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If it's checked exception - extend Exception class, if it's unchecked exception - extend RuntimeException.

Go with unchecked - you can catch them, but you don't have to declare them.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: It depends on the context if you should use checked or unchecked exceptions. Uncaught exceptions cause your program to end, so if you go for unchecked you should at least have a general exception handler at some level that can deal with the exception.

Answer (score 0):

**BY USING SUPER**

```
class OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError extends Exception 
    {

        public OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError(String s)
        {
            super(s);
        }
    }
```

You can also do this ; if you dont want to use super then we can use this here..

**BY USING THIS.**

```
  class OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError extends Exception {
     public OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError(String s)
        this.s=s
        public String toString();
        {
        return s
        }
}
```

**Now, lets implement it.**

```
class Temp
{
int age;
void get(int someThing) Throws OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError
{
if(Your condition)
{
throw new OwnExceptionAboutTechnicalError("your message");
}
```

Comment: thank you. should i post my custom made exception's code here?@NikhilJoshi

Comment: I think your answer is sufficient, no need.

Comment: Your example using this is wrong. An Exception still needs to extend `Exception` - that is missing. And if you do it like this, you should also override getMessage(), and potentially other methods. Otherwise your Exception won't be formatted correctly, when you use `printStackTrace`